# How to use WhereBetween date with %LIKE% in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my database creadted_at data  `2017-11-07 18:58:16,2017-11-07 19:58:16`. I try to use WhereBetween for searching data in date 2017-11-07
Am not sure How can I put `Like % %` into my query

```
 'like', '%'.2017-11-07.'%'

 ->WhereBetween('created_at', ['2017-11-07', '2017-12-07'])
```

Here is my full controller

```
  $b = DB::table("v_dealer_sell_time")
             ->select([
                    'product_name',
                    DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(total_price), 0) AS total_price'),
                    DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(total_product), 0) AS total_product')
                    ])
            ->WhereBetween('created_at', ['2017-11-07', '2017-11-07'])
            ->groupBy('product_name')
            ->get();
```

Comment: You want data that are created in the same day as 2017-11-07

Comment: Opps i updated it's between 2017-11-07 and 2017-12-07

Comment: what is the version of laravel ?

Comment: laravel 5.4 @Maraboc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the created ones in the same given date you can use `whereDate` like this But since 5.3 ([Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses)):

```
$b = DB::table("v_dealer_sell_time")
             ->select([
                    'product_name',
                    DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(total_price), 0) AS total_price'),
                    DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(total_product), 0) AS total_product')
                    ])
            ->WhereDate('created_at', '=', $date)
            ->groupBy('product_name')
            ->get();
```

---

If you want it from between two dates use whereBetween like this :

```
$b = DB::table("v_dealer_sell_time")
             ->select([
                    'product_name',
                    DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(total_price), 0) AS total_price'),
                    DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(total_product), 0) AS total_product')
                    ])
            ->WhereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::parse('2017-11-07')->startOfDay(), Carbon::parse('2017-12-07')->endOfDay()])
            ->groupBy('product_name')
            ->get();
```

PS : Do not forget to add `use Carbon\Carbon;` at the top of your Controller.

Comment: Opps i updated it's between 2017-11-07 and 2017-12-07

Answer (score 1):

Use `whereDate()`:

```
$date = Carbon::parse($date)->toDateString();
....
->whereDate('created_at', $date)
```

Or `whereBetween()`:

```
$date = Carbon::parse($date);
$from = $date->copy()->startOfDay();
$to = $date->copy()->endOfDay();
....
->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])
```

Answer (score 1):

> **If this Date search related to a Search Function, then you have to do something like this**

---

**Code**

Change this to

```
->WhereBetween('created_at', ['2017-11-07', '2017-11-07'])
```

this

```
->WhereBetween('created_at', ['2017-11-07 00:00:00', '2017-11-07 23:59:59'])
```

**WHY ??**

`2017-11-07 00:00:00` - Start of the day
`2017-11-07 23:59:59` - end of the day

---

> if you use `tosql()` and check your query it has something like this

```
.`created_at` between ? and ? "
```

Comment: may I ask you to take a look at a Laravel search related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76485513/laravel-search-with-multiple-keywords-against-multiple-columns-with-the-search?